# Windows Preinstall environmentでのPythonの実行

Tags: python, windows

Windows Preinstall environment(WinPE)で，Pythonを動かす方法ってないですか？

Comment: WinPE のどのバージョンか指定はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

Windows用の「Embedded Python」が、WinPEで動作すると思われます。

Windows用の「Embedded Python」は、Pythonの[Windowsダウンロード](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)から、WinPEが32bit版か64bit版により `Windows x86 embeddable zip file`又は`Windows x64 embeddable zip file`をダウンロードすることで入手できます。

参考: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5ql6j0/python_and_winpe/

Comment: 返信が遅くなり大変申し訳ございません。
Embedded Pythonで無事動作することができました。

ありがとうございました！